# "there is no such" vs "there is no such a..."

Tags: articles

I often meet two constructions which differ, as it seems, only by the choice of article: "there is no such [condition ...]" and "there is no such  a [condition ...]". What actually is the difference between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*There's* or *There is no such thing* is the only grammatical way to say it. Using an **a** is a red flag that signals a non-native speaker.

Comment: And yet, ironically, there **is** such a thing as _there is such a thing_. To quote Oscar Wilde: _there is such a thing as leaving mankind alone; there is no such thing as governing mankind_. So the **a** isn't _always_ a "red flag"; only in the negative idiomatic expression.

Comment: The OP's structure is a red flag: **there is no such a [condition]**; Your example is: There is such A thing AS. Not the same structure at all.

Comment: Lambie - And the learner would be able to pick up on that, based on your answer here? (I'm not saying it's the same, I'm merely saying that it merits fleshing out a little bit more, and that an _a_ in this type of construct is not always a "red flag".)

Comment: I didn't give an answer. I was answering the question: can there be such a [something]. No, there cannot. No need to go on and on and on.

Comment: Can there be such a thing as too much helpful information?

Answer (score -1):

Let's say I put the word "thing" at the end of the sentences.  Then, you have two complete sentences. The first is both grammatically and stylistically correct, while the second is only marginally grammatically correct.

Remember the rule: **Less is more**.  If you can express yourself in fewer words without losing meaning, then you should.  Sure, you *can* use "there is no such a thing" and get away with it, but "there is no such thing" *sounds* better and is probably the one a native speaker would use.

Comment: Err... Doesn't your first paragraph contradict the second?

Comment: @Serguei Oh, sorry, they were in different orders in your title and the body of your question.  Can you edit your question to be consistent with the title?

Comment: _No such a thing_ is agrammatical in English. It is not correct. The _a_ is an immediate red flag.

Comment: @Lambie You're probably right, and I thought so, but I don't know for sure and that's why I didn't say that it's not correct.  If you're sure, however, then I can change it.